# Javascript returning different output than expected

Tags: javascript

I'm working through CoderByte and am having troubles understanding why the output isn't as I believe it should be.  The function below takes in an array, and then returns whether that array is an Arithmetic sequence, Geometric sequence, or none at all (in that case, return -1).  However, no matter what array I pass in (bigger than 1 element), it outputs "Arithmetic".  For a test case, I pass in: [5,10,20] which should output "Geometric", as well as [1,2,3,100] which should output -1.  What am I doing incorrectly?

```
 function ArithGeo(arr) { 
  if (arr.length == 1){
    return "too short";
  }
  var arrDiff=arr[1]-arr[0];
  var geoDiff=arr[1]/arr[0];
  var arr=true;
  var geo=true;
  var diff=0;
  for (var i=1; i<arr.length;i++){
    diff = arr[i+1]-arr[i];
    if(diff != arrDiff){
      arrDiff=false;
    }
    if (diff != geoDiff){
      geoDiff=false;
    }
  }
  if (arr == true){
    return "Arithmetic";
  } else if (geo == true){
    return "Geometric";
  } else {
    return -1;
  }

}
```

Comment: you are overwriting your "arr" variable to true at line 7.

Comment: You're muddling your variables. Look long and hard at what you're doing  with `arr`, `arrDiff`, `geo` and `geoDiff`. Note also that you're not calculating the geometric difference properly for that test.

Comment: unreal. thanks @progysm I didn't even realize I was using the same name as the parameter itself. If you add the answer, I'll mark it as correct/upvote. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Thanks @MikeW as well. My mistake was not checking the variable names.. the help here is much appreciated. Back to the drawing board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with masking a variable.  Your function takes as an argument `arr` but you also define a variable named `arr`.

Try changing the variable line 6 to be `arithmetic` or something similar

```
function ArithGeo(arr) { 
  if (arr.length == 1){
    return "too short";
  }
  var arrDiff=arr[1]-arr[0];
  var geoDiff=arr[1]/arr[0];
  var arrithmetic=true;
  var geo=true;
  var diff=0;
  for (var i=1; i<arr.length;i++){
    diff = arr[i+1]-arr[i];
    if(diff != arrDiff){
      arrDiff=false;
    }
    if (diff != geoDiff){
      geoDiff=false;
    }
  }
  if (arrithmetic == true){
    return "Arithmetic";
  } else if (geo == true){
    return "Geometric";
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @NuclearGhost - this is spot on.  Additionally, after MikeW's suggestion above I realized I made another dumb error which was setting arrDiff/geoDiff to false, rather than arr/geo (now arithm/geo).  I can't accept for 7 more minutes, but I will as soon as I can. much appreciated